# Adding description task field to approval email in workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, workflow-tasks-list

In SharePoint Online, I have a task list with default fields like 'Assigned to' and 'Description', and an approval workflow made in SharePoint Designer 2013.

Whenever the assigned person adds a description in the task field and approves the decision, this description should appear in the mail sent to the person who created the task. How do I implement this in the workflow? I tried the following but it doesn't work. I also tried it with ID instead of GUID but no success.

[image]

Is there a way to make this possible without custom code but only with workflows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Last time I didn't work with Workflow variables and parameters, now I did and it works. Check the screenshot below for the screenshot.

PS: opmerkingen = description field

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Configure your Workflow like this and then you'll get description in your mail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but maybe I wasn't clear enough. I have a custom list with list workflow and action 'Assign a task to...'. When the task is approved and the approver sets a description in the description task field, it needs to return this description in a mail in another list. That's why I need to work with Assiociation Task list. But I found the solution, check my answer.